# Forma mais rápida API REST - PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, api, rest

Bom dia povo Stack overflow!!

Seguinte, estou fazendo uma integração junto ao meu banco `Sql server` de uma API*Rest*, onde eu passo a informação que eu quero na URL e recebo o conteúdo como `json`, no entanto, eu realizo várias requisições nessa API, pois eu faço um `SELECT` no meu banco que retorna todos os ID's das oportunidades de venda e eu passo esse ID na url da API, só que de vez em quando ocorre alguns erros pois a API permite apenas 100 requisições a cada 10 segundos, coloquei um contador para realizar um `sleep`, mas mesmo assim o erro continua, segue código abaixo:

```
while($RFP = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

//contador que coloquei para o limite da requisição da api
   if($contador >= 96){
         $contador = 0;
         sleep(10); // 5 segundos para proxima requisitar da API
   }
   $url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/".$RFP['ID']."/flow?start=0&api_token=meutokenaqui";
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $cAlljson = curl_exec($ch);
   // liberar
   curl_close($ch);

   $contador = $contador + 1;  // Contador para limite de requisições da API

   // Decodifica o Json em Objeto
   $cAlljson = json_decode($cAlljson);
   $cAlljson = $cAlljson->data;



   if (is_array($cAlljson)){
   foreach($cAlljson as $e)
     {
```

Comment: Bom dia, pelo que eu vi da [documentação](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1) da API, eles retornam no header os cabeçalhos `X-RateLimit-Limit`, `X-RateLimit-Remaining`, `X-RateLimit-Reset`. Você pode printa-los a cada requisição para debugar e ver se é isto que está causando os erros. Além disto, se você não tem pressa de fazer esta carga (pelo que eu entendi), sugiro colocar um `sleep` a cada requisição (um segundo de repente, ou meio), para não bombardear a API deles com reqs consecutivas (pode ser em razão disto o erro, alguma proteção/firewall de flood). Mas é só um palpite.

Comment: Tem também pode checar o header `Retry-After`: _In case the limit is exceeded for the time window, the Pipedrive API will return an error response with HTTP code 429 and Retry-After header that will incicate the amount of seconds before the limit resets._

Comment: Consegui resolver com a questão do x-ratelimit-limit, obrigado, não tinha me atentado nessa questão.